# Maid RPG: encouraging people to roleplay

Tags: roleplaying, maid

Maid RPG is fun, but when we try to play it with our group we find that we're a bit too British: we're not extroverted enough, and too easily embarrassed. We end up playing it more like paranoia: all trying not to reveal our cards or do anything risky.

Short of alcohol, what would people suggest to get players to open up?

Comment: "If you are already from the UK in real life, then you are now DOUBLE BRITISH." (p.15)

Answer (score 10):

From the website:

### The Theme

> Maid is a game where all the players are maids who serve a master. The gamemaster, or "GM", plays the role of the master. It is by default a lighthearted anime-themed roleplaying game of conflict, friendship, romance, and overcoming adversity for the sake of the master. Crazy events happen all the time in the mansion; a yakuza crime boss shows up with a deed to the mansion, claiming ownership; a meteorite crashes into the garden, from which a strange alien princess emerges; a giant robot threatens the city, including the mansion. The maids have to deal with all these events while at the same time making sure the master is protected and well cared for.
>
> This game is rated Older Teen: Age 16+.

As reserved as you feel you are, this is an open door to go nuts.  Japanese culture is just as reserved (if not more so) than you Brits.  This game is an outlet for that craziness.  Were this game a movie, look it as more of "Sharktopus" than "Gone with the Wind" or "Casa Blanca".  It's a good bit of fun and that's it.

IN terms of actual advice, I'd say do whatever an Anime would do and then have a good laugh.  Get your fellow gamers in a contest to see who can "out-maid" the others.  Everything I read from the game indicates that is what the authors had in mind.

Comment: I'll note that that's how you are supposed to play Paranoia as well...  Sounds like an entrenched focus on "winning" over "fun."

Comment: I wouldn't emphasize winning over fun.  I would emphasize the antics over the actual/inferred "goal" of pleasing master and becoming his favorite maid.  I think this would be one of those fun games where you backstab other characters just to get everyone else to laugh.  As long as it's give and take (in roughly equal measures), then it's all good.

Comment: I saw a story about Sharktopus.  I'm actually half bummed that I apparently missed that train-wreck of a movie.

Comment: @mxyzplk Wait, isn't maid one of the games where optimized play involves seducing everyone else? It doesn't sound like they are doing that either, and, probably, that doing that would make things more to their liking. So on that note, seduce all the other player's characters.

Answer (score 5):

This game is a super duper toolkit, which means that the advice here and there are namely about two things, helping you hit your stride.

Presuming your britishness hasn't gotten in the way of your other roleplaying, there are two problems.

A> Playing a different gender then yourself.

B> Playing romantic situations with others.

Because the game is a super duper toolkit, there are some options to avoid A> (Butlers, come to mind) and some options to avoid B> (put the focus on something else except the true love scenario that the book recommends at time.)

The Game is ridiculsy easy to drift over to whatever style of play you want that revolves arround a strong (or not so strong) authority figure and just as strong subordinates. Chances are I think B> is actually the problem, but is also the source of many lolz in the game, so I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 5):

Institute some kind of out-of-character "dare" mechanic. "I dare you to..."